# How can I check with JQuery, if a certain word is typed in the Browser?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

This is a funny one, I want to display a certain div on a website only if a secret word is typed on that page (no forms are present).
What is the easiest way to accomplish this with JQuery? Are there any Plugins?
Thanx in advance
cheers Tabaluga

Comment: How/where do you want the user to type this word?

Comment: No forms? You mean no text input at all?

Comment: So what you're saying is that they just type, not into any kind of textbox? Sort of a konami-code type thing?

Comment: If it is his active tab or window in the browser he should just type it. Yes, it is a kind of konami-code thing :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
        var kkeys = [], konami = "68,73,78,78,69,82"; //this spells dinner
        window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
                kkeys.push( e.keyCode );
                if ( kkeys.toString().indexOf( konami ) >= 0 ) {
                    // run code here    
                    $("#text").hide().fadeIn("slow").html('Now the website will appear.');
                }
        }, true);
}
```

you can check what letters are what by doing:

```
if ( window.addEventListener ) {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
        $("#text").append(e.keyCode + " ");
    }, true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try using [js-Hotkey jquery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/js-hotkeys/wiki/about):

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 's+e+c+r+e+t', fn);
```

Also you may want to inspect through [KonamiCodeWebsites](http://konamicodesites.com/) to see how it works:

In this website you need to enter konami code (UP + UP + DN + DN + LFT + LFT + RGT + RGT + B + A) in order to enter the website!

Answer (score 2):

Pure javascript:

```
var typedWord = '';
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){
  var c = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  typedWord += c.toLowerCase();
  if(typedWord.length > 4) typedWord = typedWord.slice(1);
  if(typedWord == 'jogo') alert('JOGO');
});
```

http://codepen.io/rafaelcastrocouto/pen/xeGps

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div style="display: none" class="secret">Correct password!</div>
```

JS:

```
var pass="password";
var typed="";

$(document).keypress(
    function (e) {
       typed += String.fromCharCode(e.which);

       if (typed===pass) {
           $('.secret').show();
       }
    }
);
```

If you're familiar with Javascript closures you can get rid of the global variables like this:

```
$(document).keypress((function(e) {
    var pass = "password";
    var typed = "";

    return function(e) {
        typed += String.fromCharCode(e.which);

        console.log(typed);
        if (typed === pass) {
            $('.secret').show();
        }
    };
})());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to listen to keyboard events.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var currentKey = 0;
    var validKeyArray = [22,23,24]; //list of valid keys to listen to in order
    $('body').keyup(function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == validKeyArray[currentKey]){
            currentKey ++;
        } else {
            currentKey = 0;
        }
        if (currentKey == validKeyArray.length){
           // SUCCESS! Do your magic div right here!
           // console.log('SUCCESS!');
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: No problem... I actually think that success conditional should be `if(currentKey == validKeyArray.length-1)`  whoops! :-)

Comment: i think its ````keyCode```` camelcase

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what you can do: http://jsfiddle.net/Akkuma/CGmnw/

This is a prototype for clarification. Basically what this is doing is it maintains an array of keycodes that must be pressed in that order. It then increments the checking and resets when an incorrect key is detected or time runs out to enter it.

The prototype offers both resetting on incorrect keypress and after a certain amount of time elapsed.