# jQuery -hot key combinations

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check with JQuery, if a certain word is typed in the Browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655335/how-can-i-check-with-jquery-if-a-certain-word-is-typed-in-the-browser)

Ok, I have found this great plugin in order to capture and execute hot key commands for jQuery. 
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys

My question before I get too involved in this is that I noticed the "+" between the keys. I was looking for something that would capture what the user enters after typing a string.

the goal is to call a function that will show quick data on a "job" that is stored in the database. For example: (all of this is key stroked not holding down the combination)

If the user types this combination: c v l

then a function is called to listen for the next command. The user then types: 1 2 3

this would then fire another function to find job: 123 from the database.

Basically I am looking for an idea on how this might be possible. If anyone has any idea or if I need to provide more details please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simple add a keyup function and look at the keys that being pressed. So something like this pseudocode:

```
my_array_interesting_keys = [c,v,l]
current_sequence = null

window.onKeyup:
   if(key in my_array_interesting_keys) {
      current_sequence[] = key
   } else {
      current_sequence = null 
      // abort current sequence
   }

   if(current_sequence.length == 3) {
       if(implode('', current_sequence) == implode('', my_array_interesting_keys)) {
          // wait for number to be entered now
       } else {
          current_sequence = null
       }
   }
```

Obviously this would need to be refined and converted into actual JS.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the samples for that plugin correctly, it doesn't do multi key sequences, only individual key events. e.g. hit 'a', it fires up a handler and says A was hit. it doesn't sit and wait for 'b' and 'c' to come before firing the event.

This means you'd have to have the keypress handler keep track of previous key presses, and only move to the next stage if an appropriate key was pressed.

e.g. user enters 'c' then 'v' - good, that's a good sequence. but if they enter '#' next, then you empty the accumulator because cv# doesn't mean anything. if they enter 'l' as the 3rd character, then you can pop  up a prompt for the record ID, etc...